# Can I pass and return data with passport.js for github calls?

Tags: node.js, github, passport.js

Here's my use case.... a user is invited to my service by email address. They get a link in the mail: `mysite.com/invite/[uniqueToken]`. Once they click on that, they should be redirected to `github` for authentication. In the callback, I want to pass that token back to my service so that I can associate this user with the referral.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have the [`OAuth authentication`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) from github, so you should have a look at the [github developer API's here](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

Basically, you will need to create [a new application on github](https://github.com/settings/applications/new), where you can specify the callback url.

Once a user comes to your site from the link you generated, you redirect your users to the `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` with a `GET` request, and github comes back to you with the `code` parameter.

***EDIT***

From [the developer API's](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls), you can pass back the additional `redirect_uri` parameter with each request to be used for redirecting back. Within this parameter, reference to the token can be passed from your end.

> The `redirect_uri` parameter is optional. If left out, GitHub will redirect users to the callback URL configured in the OAuth Application settings. If provided, the redirect URL’s host and port must exactly match the callback URL. The redirect URL’s path must reference a subdirectory of the callback URL.

Comment: This is actually not what I need. I can authorize no problem - but I want to pass a token back to my callback URL that I pass to the github auth url

Comment: @Shamoon Check edits. I think you need [this `redirect_uri`](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls) parameter.

Comment: @Shamoon I don't think you can do it with a get parameter, but you should definitely be able to do `redirect_uri=http://example.com/auth/callback/token/123`